# Standard SQL Query Efficiency

Tags: google-bigquery

Which of the two queries below would be more efficient query-wise and better in terms of etiquette? Is there a difference? Just trying to see which would be better so I can get in the habit of trying to make my queries a bit more efficient.

```
select
a,
b,
c

from TABLE1
left join TABLE2

union all

select
d,
e,
f
from TABLE3
left join TABLE2
```

or

```
with TABLES as (
select
a,
b,
c
from TABLE1

union all

select
d,
e,
f
from TABLE3)

select *

from TABLES
left join TABLE2
```

Comment: For etiquette, see the Software Engineering Stack Exchange. Also, what do you mean by "efficient query-wise"?

Comment: By _"etiquette"_ do you mean _easier to read_? If so, please edit and rephrase your question.

Comment: You can know more about the Bigquery best practices to optimizing query performance in here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview

Answer (score 1):

In general, I find it good practice to minimize joins when using BQ.  Because it is a columnar database, unions are pretty 'easy'.  However, your example is a bit unclear, as `TABLE1` and `TABLE3` have different columns (`a,b,c` vs `d,e,f`).  If the join to `TABLE2` is **different** for each table, then I would recommend doing the joins first and *then* unioning the results, instead of trying a more complicated join later on.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on indexes and table sizes. Most databases have a way to explain how it handles queries. Many databases have the keyword EXPLAIN for that. Try it, or something similar for your database.